# Sharing a variable among 2 c++ file not located in the same directory

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I have two c++ files. 
One (AudioSystem.cpp) located at `./framework/av/media/libmedia` 
The other (AudioFlinger.cpp) locatet at `./framework/av/services/audioflinger`

Both they share an header file

```
#include <system/audio.h>
```

I would like to create a var that is shared among the AudioFlinger.cpp and the AudioSystem.cpp.

They both should be able to modify the var value and they should see the same value.

Thanks

Comment: Two C++ files, so why the C tag?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? First think of why? because most likely there is a better solution.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c?rq=1) might be somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variable can be defined in any of your AudioFlinger.cpp or AudioSystem.cpp, but you should ensure that in other cpp file the statement declaring this variable as `extern` in placed e.g. with h-file and `#include`.

Also, you can make separate cpp-file with variable definition and appropriate h-file with extarn variable declaration, e.g.:

```
   // var.cpp
   int sharedVariable;
```

and

```
   // var.h
   extern int sharedVariable;
```

And now any cpp module, where `#include "var.h"` is, can use `sharedVariable`

Comment: Following your suggestion I get: frameworks/av/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp:736: error: undefined reference to 'sharedVariable'

Comment: If you written `extern data_type var_name;` in `frameworks/av/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp` you should compile this cpp file together with cpp file where `data_type var_name;` (global declaration means outside of a function) is